# Sampling Rate of imfreehand tool in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, sampling, onmousemove

I wanted to use `imfreehand` to hand-draw paths in the MATLAB Plot. For analysis purpose, I need the sampling rate of the `imfreehand` tool. Does it use time sampling or space sampling ?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is, that it does *neither* time or space sampling. It attempts to do spatial sampling but is ultimately limited by a system-specific temporal sampling rate.

**More info**

Any callback bound to the [`WindowButtonMotionFcn` of a figure](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#property_windowbuttonmotionfcn), is executed *only* when the mouse changes position.

> This callback function executes whenever the user moves the pointer within the figure window.

Under the hood, `imfreehand` sets a custom callback for the `WindowButtonMotionFcn` and is therefore subject to the same constraint.

For the `imfreehand` tool, this is beneficial so that you will not record multiple points at the same location while the mouse is not moving. What this also means though, is that the sampling rate is variable.

What the *fastest* sampling rate is really depends on the system. You are not guaranteed (for example) to get a sample every time your mouse moves a pixel because it is rate-limited by the system. So if you move your mouse very quickly across the figure, all pixels positions between the start and end locations will not be registered.

If you actually need the mouse position to be sampled at a specific rate, it is best to use a [`timer` object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer-class.html) instead.

```
%// Sampling rate in Hz
samplingRate = 30;

t = timer('ExecutionMode', 'FixedRate', ...
          'Period', 1/samplingRate, ...
          'TimerFcn', @(s,e)disp(get(gcf, 'CurrentPoint')));

start(t);
```

Answer (score 1):

As Suever explained, neither. `imfreehand` is implemented as an event-triggered handler called on mouse-move/down/up, similar to UI frameworks in other languages.

The rate at which it gets triggered depends on the how fast the system/program can [pump messages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop). What you can do is specify how triggered events get queued (see the `Interruptible` and `BusyAction` properties).